# Make Node MongoDB driver return bson classes for queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using Node MongoDB driver (`mongodb`) to do some simple `db.collection.find()`. I then `stringify` using `bson`s `EJSON`, send it and might re-use it for MongoDB at the other end.

To preserve data type I'd like for the `Document` instances to always use the bson classes like `Int32` and `Long`, however the result appears to be `number` a lot of the time and then `Long` when required.

Is there any way to enforce using the bson classes?

Comment: I think, in the newer MongoDB versions, int, long, double and decimal are generally classified as a "number" type. By default, a number is an int (or double, in earlier versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term for the conversion being done from bson classes to closest JavScript equivalent is apparently `promoteValues` ([API reference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.5/interfaces/FindOptions.html#promoteValues)). Essentially:

> when deserializing will promote BSON values to their Node.js closest equivalent types.

It can be used in most operations, e.g.:

```js
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"
const client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
const collection = client.db("mydatabase").collection("mycollection")
const cursor = collection.find({}, { promoteValues: false }) // keep bson classes
```